# Socket: get socket() in the server code

Tags: c, sockets

I trying to return a result of socket() in the following server code:

```
#include "sys/socket.h"
#include "sys/types.h"
int main(void)
{   
    int listenfd = 0,connfd = 0;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    char sendBuff[1025];  
    int numrv;  
    listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    printf("socket retrieve success\n");
    return(listenfd);
}
```

I do the gcc to this code and it worked well,but when I execute it,it return nothing.

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing"?  `socket()` returns an `int`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. You are labouring under some misapprehension about what might happen with this code.  Firstly, your `printf()` says 'success' regardless of whether the `socket()` call passed or failed; you don't pay any attention to its return value before declaring success. Secondly, your code returns the value from `socket()`, which is likely to be 3 or -1, as the exit status from the program.  The exiting process closes the socket file descriptor, but the calling program (a shell, for example) can determine that the socket file descriptor was 3.

Comment: You have a basic error here. You are printing success before you've tested for error. In fact you aren't testing for error here at all. *And,* by calling printf(), you are probably destroying the errno value that tells you what the error was, if there was an error.

Comment: [Not reproducible, compilation errors](http://ideone.com/601TnI).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If successful [`socket()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socket.2.html) returns an integer file descriptor for the new socket. If there was an error, -1 is returned. You can inspect the error code in `errno`, and can print out a text version of it using `perror()`.

Note that you need to `#include <netinet/in.h>` for the definition of `struct sockaddr_in`.

This might aid your understanding:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

int main(void)
{
    int listenfd = 0,connfd = 0;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    char sendBuff[1025];
    int numrv;
    listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (listenfd == -1) {
        printf("Failed to create socket: errno = %d\n", errno);
        perror("Failed to create socket");
    }
    else
        printf("socket created, fd = %d\n", listenfd);
    return(listenfd);
}
```